# Elixir: Compilation of fs suddenly fails with rebar_abort

Tags: elixir

The compilation of the deps of a project suddenly started to fail without any major code change or upgrade to Elixir or Erlang.

#### Environment

- Elixir v 1.6.4, Erlang 20.3.4
- Operating system: Mac OS 10.13.4

**My deps:**

```
certifi 2.0.0
connection 1.0.4
cowboy 2.2.0
cowlib 2.1.0
db_connection 1.1.3
earmark 1.2.4
ex_doc 0.18.3
excoveralls 0.8.1
exjsx 4.0.0
fs 0.9.2
grpc 0.3.0-alpha.2
gun 1.0.0-pre.5
hackney 1.11.0
idna 5.1.0
jsx 2.8.3
metrics 1.0.1
mimerl 1.0.2
mix_test_watch 0.5.0
morphix 0.2.1
poison 3.1.0
poolboy 1.5.1
protobuf 0.5.4
ranch 1.4.0
retry 0.8.1
ssl_verify_fun 1.1.1
unicode_util_compat 0.3.1
uuid 1.1.8
```

**Terminal output:**

```
$: mix deps.compile
==> protobuf
Compiling 21 files (.ex)
Generated protobuf app
==> connection
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Generated connection app
==> fs (compile)
Compiled src/fs_app.erl
Compiled src/fs.erl
Compiled src/fs_server.erl
Compiled src/fs_event_bridge.erl
Compiled src/fs_sup.erl
Compiled src/sys/fsevents.erl
Compiled src/sys/inotifywait_win32.erl
Compiled src/sys/inotifywait.erl
Compiling c_src/mac/cli.c
In file included from c_src/mac/cli.c:2:
In file included from c_src/mac/cli.h:4:
In file included from c_src/mac/common.h:4:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:
/usr/local/include/Block.h:16:3: error: Never include this file directly. Use <lzma.h> instead.
#       error Never include this file directly. Use <lzma.h> instead.
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:93:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_check'
        lzma_check check;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:148:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli compressed_size;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:172:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli uncompressed_size;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:200:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_filter'
        lzma_filter *filters;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:217:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_CHECK_SIZE_MAX'
        uint8_t raw_check[LZMA_CHECK_SIZE_MAX];
                          ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:231:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int3;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:232:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int4;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:233:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int5;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:234:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int6;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:235:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int7;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:236:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int8;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:237:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_reserved_enum'
        lzma_reserved_enum reserved_enum1;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:238:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_reserved_enum'
        lzma_reserved_enum reserved_enum2;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:239:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_reserved_enum'
        lzma_reserved_enum reserved_enum3;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:240:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_reserved_enum'
        lzma_reserved_enum reserved_enum4;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:261:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_bool'
        lzma_bool ignore_check;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:263:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_bool'
        lzma_bool reserved_bool2;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:264:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_bool'
        lzma_bool reserved_bool3;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
ERROR: compile failed while processing /Users/olespaarmann/Sites/exdgraph/deps/fs: rebar_abort
==> ex_dgraph
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :fs, "/Users/olespaarmann/.mix/rebar compile skip_deps=true deps_dir="/Users/olespaarmann/Sites/exdgraph/_build/dev/lib"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile fs", update it with "mix deps.update fs" or clean it with "mix deps.clean fs"
```

**What I tried so far:**

```
$ rm -rf deps
$ rm -rf _build
$ mix deps.get
$ mix deps.compile
```

- Restarting Mac
- Starting Xcode to see if everything is working
- Upgrading homebrew
- Installing Xcode Command Line Tools because Brew said they are missing with `xcode-select --install`
- Everything above again

Via https://github.com/synrc/fs/issues/44:

```
$ locate /CoreServices.h
$ export CFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include"
```

- Make sure no global version of rebar is installed.
- Run `mix local.rebar`

Nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

Running `brew doctor` revealed: "Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include."

Deleting these files did the trick for me.